# Flask RESTful error handling when catch all exists

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

We're using Flask-RESTful to define an API of the form,

```
bp = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(bp)

@api.resource('/users/<int:user>')
class User(Resource):
    def get(self, user):
        ...
```

in conjunction with a [Catch-All](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/) to render all the pages using React.

```
bp = Blueprint('index', __name__)

@bp.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@bp.route('/<path:path>')
def index(path):
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The issue is requests which don't match a valid API endpoint are supposed to return a [404](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html#endpoints), however given the Catch-All logic all unregistered API routes simply route to rendering the template.

Is there a good way to ensure that invalid API requests return a 404? There doesn't seem to be a way to exclude routes from the Catch-All so my current workaround is to define something like,

```
from werkzeug.routing import NotFound

@api.resource('/<path:path>')
class Endpoint(Resource):
    def get(self, path):
        raise NotFound()

    def put(self, path):
        raise NotFound()

    def post(self, path):
        ...
```

which seems a little verbose.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like simply overriding the `dispatch_request` method is suffice.

```
@api.resource('/<path:path>')
class Endpoint(Resource):
    def dispatch_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotFound()
```